# Will upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 work with LVM encryption?

Tags: upgrade, lvm

I have a laptop running 12.04 and the HD is encrypted with LVM. Will the system boot if I upgrade to 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

In general the upgrade system will work but if we all say "yes" to your question and the system does not what then?! Maybe it can be fixed, maybe not. But at that moment you have a problem that might need a format or a rebuild of your system. Who knows.

Your problem has a very simple solution: make a backup and make sure you know how to and that you can restore that backup.